# Overlapping matches in regex? (rust regex engine)

Tags: regex, rust

I am currently trying to solve [Advent of Code 2023 day 1](https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/1), but part two has phrases like `threeight` that I am unsure how to match. My original approach was `(?:[0-9]|zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine)`, but this doesn't support the overlap between spelled-out numbers.

I know the `regex` crate doesn't support lookarounds, but even with them I don't see how to do it with the [0-9] in the same regex.

Comment: For that particular problem, it's much easier to just search for the first and last occurence of a match separately and then replace & concatenate them (or concatenate & replace) bypassing the need to match overlapping digits alltogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know the regex crate doesn't support lookarounds, but even with them I don't see how to do it with the [0-9] in the same regex.

You can capture in a lookahead assertion, but the lookahead assertion does not actually *match* anything. So if you lookahead then match just a single character the "lookahead capture" will be applied to every single index, and thus you'll get every possible occurrence.

> I am unsure how to match.

The simple solution is to extract matches [one at a time](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.find_at). When you have the first capture, you can retrieve its [start index](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Match.html#method.start), increment that (normally you'd have to jump to the next `char`, but AOC is all ascii so you can just increment by one byte), then look for the next match.

An alternative is to use [`RegexSet`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.RegexSet.html) since it supports matching

> possibly overlapping

regexes: instead of building an alternation group you just use each digit as a regex in the set. Although that only tells you which regexes matched so you still need to re-check if multiple regexes matched, to know what the high and low are.

Finally, you can go lower and use the underlying [aho-corasick](https://docs.rs/aho-corasick/), the actual algorithm will find overlapping occurrences by default, so [that's supported out of the box](https://docs.rs/aho-corasick/latest/aho_corasick/struct.AhoCorasick.html#method.find_overlapping_iter).

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already done this, but I did it by looking for the first match, then reversing both the search string and the strings in the regex and searching for the first match in the reversed string.